# Can't install Scrapy on PC regarding multiple steps

Tags: pip, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy on PC but keep getting error messages.

I tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio and other types of things, but NOTHING works :(

```
 src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2229): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 2
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2492): warning C4022: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2838): warning C4022: 'PostQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2949): warning C4022: 'CloseHandle': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(3292): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(4932): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5149): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6182): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
c:\users\emeron\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Comment: Hi, there is no clear indication of what exact version of scrappy and Visual Studio that you are using. This makes helping you problematic because the issue could be as simple as you're using mismatched versions and need another version of scrappy (for example) to use in VS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using VS Buildtools with pyclipper install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462530/using-vs-buildtools-with-pyclipper-install-error)

Answer (score 1):

The `tp_print` method was removed from the API in Python 3.8. Error "*'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'*" means that the code is intended for Python <= 3.8. Downgrade to Python 3.8 and try again.

Currently at version 20.3.0 Twisted [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted/20.3.0/#files) up to Python 3.7 so may be you should downgrade even further.

PS. Never hurry to a newer major version of Python, wait until all your 3rd-party libraries adapt.