# pip install Twister throws really long error

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to follow a tutorial online for a project using django channels. Trying to install the requirements.txt resulted in an error when trying to install Twisted==16.4.0, so I tried just pip install Twisted to see if the latest version results in the same error.

And it did. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, I ran into a very similar problem trying to install greenlet for a flask-socketio project, which made me give up and try django channels. This is quite demotivating.

I did this in a virtual environment, I think there might be something wrong with my visual studio C++ stuff? I really can't gleam anything from this error, seeing as to how it's so long and I'm really new to this.

Here's the error:

```
    iocpsupport.c
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2229): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 2
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2492): warning C4022: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2838): warning C4022: 'PostQueuedCompletionStatus': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2949): warning C4022: 'CloseHandle': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(3292): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(4932): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5149): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6182): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

(full output https://pastebin.com/HwmPLVTK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgiven that you didn't spot the actual error amidst all that cruft, but this is it:

```
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614):
    error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
```

And that leads to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462530/pyclipper-installation-error-tp-print-is-not-a-member-of-typeobject) which suggests that you need to either downgrade Python from 3.9 to 3.8, or upgrade Twisted if a 3.9-compatible version has been released.

At the time of writing (2021-02-13), [ticket #10075](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/10075) reporting this same error (albeit in French) is still open, so I don't think the latest version of Twisted supports Python 3.9 yet. [The corresponding milestone](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python%203.9%20Support) is also not complete, with this issue being the only unresolved one at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it just now by downgrading to 3.7. Thank you for the help. If you don't mind, could you tell me if there's any real reason to use newer versions of python? Shouldn't I just stick to 3.7?

Comment: If you don't need any of the new features provided in later versions, there's very little reason to upgrade to the next minor version. If it's running a public web service though, it is wise to keep up with patch levels (3.7.1, etc.) because of security updates.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I appreciate the help, I got it all to work properly now, cheers!